# How to open Windows word application to edit word in WOPI

Tags: sharepoint, ms-wopi

I have installed Office Online service (WOPI server) in a particular server X. I also have WOPI client in my machine to which I pointed the discovery file of X server.

I am able to load the word file. But when I click on edit document -> Edit in Word. It gives as an error such as

[image: Error]

How can I enable the Word opening feature in WOPI? Both the WOPI server and WOPI client are in my control.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea behind WOPI is to bring **Office Online** experience to your web application and not to integrate/extend Office native apps installed on your computer. This is usually done by creating web page called [WOPI host page](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hostpage.html) that iframes Office Online service and your implementation of [WOPI protocol](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/). It enables Office Online to access and change files that are stored behind your service. For example user collaborates with some other users on the document and your service stores them in filesystem/cloud storage directly or it is a bridge that integrates with some document/content management system that does the storing in the background. I think this is what they did in box.com [online content management system](https://blog.box.com/blog/introducing-box-for-office-online). If you want to open documents stored on remote server directly using Microsoft Office app via some http url you need [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) server on the other side. Many applications, including Microsoft Office, support WebDAV natively.